# Convert all data structure to Uppercase in Perl

Tags: perl

i was wondering if there was a easy way to convert a complete data strucure (mix of HoH/Arrays) to Uppercase ?

e.g., i have a structure containing many entries like this :

```
          'oracle' => {
                    'sit' => {
                               'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                                                       'ora:morningcheck',
                                                       'ora:simpana_bkp',
                                                       'ora:oraclepatching'
                                                     ]
                             },
                    'prd' => {
                               'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                                                       'ora:morningcheck',
                                                       'ora:simpana_bkp',
                                                       'odg:oraclepatching',
                                                       'ora:oraclepatching'
                                                     ]
                             },
                    'uat' => {
                               'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                                                       'ora:morningcheck',
                                                       'ora:simpana_bkp',
                                                       'odg:oraclepatching',
                                                       'ora:oraclepatching'
                                                     ]
                             },
                    'PRD' => {
                               'ZQ01-42P-UXGROUP' => [
                                                       'socdbaud',
                                                       'oramgrp',
                                                       'wmioca',
                                                       'oramigration',
                                                       'tac'
                                                     ]
```

and i want everthing (both keys & values) in uc()
is there a neat way to do it ?

i tried this but it fails (afterwards i get : 'ORACLE' => 'HASH(0X2941738)')

```
%ds = map uc, %ds;
```

thanks for any tips!

Comment: Having a full (But minimal) example of your data structure would be nice. That one's missing multiple curly braces.

Comment: When building the hash, cant you just uc() the data when adding to the hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired conversation can be achieved with a simple conversion of data structure to JSON string, converting JSON string to upper case and then convert the string back to data structure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my($var,$data);

$var = {
    'oracle' => {
        'sit' => {
            'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                'ora:morningcheck',
                'ora:simpana_bkp',
                'ora:oraclepatching'
                ]
        },
            'prd' => {
                'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                    'ora:morningcheck',
                    'ora:simpana_bkp',
                    'odg:oraclepatching',
                    'ora:oraclepatching'
                    ]
        },
            'uat' => {
                'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                    'ora:morningcheck',
                    'ora:simpana_bkp',
                    'odg:oraclepatching',
                    'ora:oraclepatching'
                    ]
        },
            'PRD' => {
                'ZQ01-42P-UXGROUP' => [
                    'socdbaud',
                    'oramgrp',
                    'wmioca',
                    'oramigration',
                    'tac'
                    ]
        }
    }
};

$data = uc to_json($var);
$data = from_json($data);

print Dumper($data);
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ORACLE' => {
                        'SIT' => {
                                   'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                                                           'ORA:MORNINGCHECK',
                                                           'ORA:SIMPANA_BKP',
                                                           'ORA:ORACLEPATCHING'
                                                         ]
                                 },
                        'PRD' => {
                                   'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                                                           'ORA:MORNINGCHECK',
                                                           'ORA:SIMPANA_BKP',
                                                           'ODG:ORACLEPATCHING',
                                                           'ORA:ORACLEPATCHING'
                                                         ]
                                 },
                        'UAT' => {
                                   'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                                                           'ORA:MORNINGCHECK',
                                                           'ORA:SIMPANA_BKP',
                                                           'ODG:ORACLEPATCHING',
                                                           'ORA:ORACLEPATCHING'
                                                         ]
                                 }
                      }
        };
```

Comment: great and simple solution, thank you !

Answer (score 5):

You can use a recursive function that does the Right Thing (tm) depending on the type of its argument:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use experimental qw/signatures/;
use Scalar::Util qw/blessed reftype/;
use Data::Dumper;

sub to_upper($var) {
    die "Blessed objects aren't supported" if blessed $var;
    my $type = reftype $var;
    if (!defined $type) {
        return uc $var;
    } elsif ($type eq "ARRAY") {
        return [ map { to_upper($_) } @$var ]
    } elsif ($type eq "HASH") {
        my %uchash;
        while (my ($key, $val) = each %$var) {
            $uchash{uc $key} = to_upper($val);
        }
        return \%uchash;
    } elsif ($type eq "SCALAR") {
        my $uc = uc $$var;
        return \$uc;
    } else {
        die "Unsupported reference type $type";
    }
}

my $var = {
    'oracle' => {
        'sit' => {
            'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                'ora:morningcheck',
                'ora:simpana_bkp',
                'ora:oraclepatching'
                ]
        },
            'prd' => {
                'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                    'ora:morningcheck',
                    'ora:simpana_bkp',
                    'odg:oraclepatching',
                    'ora:oraclepatching'
                    ]
        },
            'uat' => {
                'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                    'ora:morningcheck',
                    'ora:simpana_bkp',
                    'odg:oraclepatching',
                    'ora:oraclepatching'
                    ]
        },
            'PRD' => {
                'ZQ01-42P-UXGROUP' => [
                    'socdbaud',
                    'oramgrp',
                    'wmioca',
                    'oramigration',
                    'tac'
                    ]
        }
    }
};

my $ucvar = to_upper $var;
print Dumper($ucvar);
```

prints out

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ORACLE' => {
                        'PRD' => {
                                   'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                                                           'ORA:MORNINGCHECK',
                                                           'ORA:SIMPANA_BKP',
                                                           'ODG:ORACLEPATCHING',
                                                           'ORA:ORACLEPATCHING'
                                                         ]
                                 },
                        'UAT' => {
                                   'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                                                           'ORA:MORNINGCHECK',
                                                           'ORA:SIMPANA_BKP',
                                                           'ODG:ORACLEPATCHING',
                                                           'ORA:ORACLEPATCHING'
                                                         ]
                                 },
                        'SIT' => {
                                   'ZQ01-42P-PBTOKEN' => [
                                                           'ORA:MORNINGCHECK',
                                                           'ORA:SIMPANA_BKP',
                                                           'ORA:ORACLEPATCHING'
                                                         ]
                                 }
                      }
        };
```

(Upper casing the keys of your hash results in duplicates and only one of them is kept)

Comment: There's no need for different approaches for arrays and for hashes. `return { map { to_upper($_) } %$var }` could be used for hashes.

Comment: thank you for spending the time showing me how to do it. The solution looks good but to be honest i was expecting that perl would have simpler "ways" of doing it, i did not imagine it would be that complex, surprisingly. it's not that simple indeed, unless we use specific modules

Comment: @olivierg "_was expecting that perl would have simpler "ways" of doing it_"  -- well you need a complex data structure, arbitrary in principle, to be traversed in order to access every element.  Why would any language have a built-in operation for that? I get the expectation but that's not a basic language need, going down arbitrary data structures.  (There are libraries that do it though)